# ADC protection for PIC microchip

Tags: pic, analog, zener

I need to protect the ADC pin of my PIC18F27K40 from over-voltage and reverse voltage for a 0-10V input measurement.

After searching the web, I found the following solution : 
[image]

When testing with the following PIC configuration for PIN RB0:
WPUB0=0
TRISB0=1
ANSELB0=1
D1 = D2 = Zener Diode 3.6V 1N4729A.
I have Vrb0 between 1.4 and 1.5 V for Vin between 0 and 1.5 V.

When I take away the 2 diodes, the RB0 voltage works fine.

Can you please help me ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: you should probably use a buffer

Comment: You can use something like BAV99. SOT-23 single package with 2 signal switching diodes.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use regular diodes, not zeners, to clamp the ADC input voltage between GND-Vd and Vcc+Vd

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using Zener diodes they are partially conducting and the current is causing voltage drops across the resistors. Use ordinary diodes such as 1N4148s.